# How i can hide and show the image in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am making one android app with help of phonegap.I need help how i can hide the image or show the image when i wanted

when my toggleswitch is off then my image which is in third page should hide if my toggleswitch is on then it will show the image

plz help me out how i can do

In HTML5:-

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <select name="toggleswitch1" id="toggleswitch1" data-theme="" data-role="slider">
            <option value="off">Off</option>
            <option value="on">On</option>
        </select>
        <a data-role="button" id="button1" data-inline="true" href="#" onclick="clickfn();">Button</a>
    </div>
```

```
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="content">
         <p>some text</p><p>some text</p>
        <a data-role="button" id="button2" data-inline="true" href="#page3" >Button</a>
    </div>
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>some text</p><p>some text</p>
        <img src="xyz image" />
                  <a data-role="button" id="button3" data-inline="true" href="#page1" >Button</a>
    </div>
```

in jquery:-

```
  $(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {
          clickfn(); 
        });


    function clickfn(){
       $('#button1').click(function(){
                  if($("#toggleswitch1 option:selected").val() == 'off'){
                  $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
                  }else{
                  $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
                  }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is property called .hide and .show where you can show or hide the images.
Let us say the id of your image is img, then

```
$('#button).click(function(){
              if($("#toggleswitch1 option:selected").val() == 'off'){
                  $("#img").hide ();
              }else{
                  $("#img").show ();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a id in your img

```
  <img id="myimg" src="xyz image" />
```

And swicth the visibility in code

```
function clickfn(){
       $('#button1').click(function(){
                  if($("#toggleswitch1 option:selected").val() == 'off'){
                      $("#myimg").hide ();
                  }else{
                      $("#myimg").show ();
                  }
                });
```

}

Comment: if my id is been creating dynamically then wht i can do

Comment: suppose my image is also coming dynamically thn how i can hide or show

Comment: if you have a id... you can do `$("#" + idReceived ).show()` / `$("#" + idReceived ).hide()`... or use a class in all img's `$(".myimgclass").show()` / `$(".myimgclass").hide()`